# Linked in dotnetopenauth -> The conversion of a datetime2 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to get a user logged in via linked in, but when they get to the default template of Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation, I get this error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion
>   of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range value.

anyone familiar with that error for this lib?

Comment: I believe I have seen this when I have had a datetime database column set to not null and I forget to assign it a value during saving a new record... look for datetime values that are not being assigned a value in whatever you are doing from your code.

Comment: thanks!! stick it in the answer for points!

Comment: awesome - glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue before using Entity Framework when I have had a DateTime database column set to not null and I did not assign it a value (I left it NULL).

Check your code and look for any DateTime properties that are marked with NotNull and ensure that you are assigning those properties values before committing your changes/saving your records.